# Ubuntu 22.04 Snap Updates issue

Tags: updates, snap, update-manager

The newly added snap refresh --hold option is written to allude to one that once set snaps will no longer be updated until one issues the --unhold option.  I have attempted to use this refresh option however when Software Updates run the snaps are also updated no matter if the hold option is in place.  I have searched for any questions on this issue and would like to have Software Updates either be decoupled from Software Updates or have Software Updates honor the --hold option

I tried both commands below and neither prevents Software Updates from "updating" snaps

```
$ sudo snap refresh --hold
```

Auto-refresh of all snaps held indefinitely

and

```
$ sudo snap refresh --hold=forever
```

Auto-refresh of all snaps held indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

`snap refresh --hold` *only* applies to the periodically trigger background updates of snapd. `snap refresh --hold` does not prevent manually trigger updates - either on the command line or the Snap Store.

You may want to apply the stronger version, which is `snap hold --refresh SNAPNAME`. This also prevents manually triggered updates like `snap refresh` *unless* you call an update for this specific snap. `snap refresh SNAPNAME` overrules `-hold` set for `SNAPNAME`.

Documentation: [Link](https://snapcraft.io/docs/keeping-snaps-up-to-date)

Comment: I read the documentation and what you state is clear. I would also like to see the output of the command reflect this better than the current.  
I also tried: [system-wide option](https://snapcraft.io/docs/set-system-options)  
$ sudo snap set system refresh.hold=forever  
$ sudo snap get system refresh.hold  
forever  << returns forever  


If this is a bad choice there was no error indicating.